# Native ui component drops frames on some phones

Tags: react-native, react-native-native-ui-component

I am trying to work around the shadow limitation on react native for android. Basically I need box shadows. My solution was to build a native ui component (java) with which I can create box shadows.

Now I ran into a weird bug. In a bare minimum app, with nothing but just some navigation and the box shadow ui components, the navigation is extremely laggy/ drops frames, when the app has to load the box shadow component.

The weird thing is. This just happens on some phones. From my tests so far I can say the **native component runs smoothly on:**

- Fairphone 3 (Snapdragon),
- Samsung galaxy s21 (Snapdragon) and
- xiaomi redmi note 9 (Snapdragon)

**The app drops frames on:**

- Samsung galax s41 (Mediatek)
- Huawei mate 20 (Kirin)
- Samsung galaxy s7 (Snapdragon)

Does anyone have an idea what the Problem could be? Does it perhaps have something to do with the CPU?
I am really gratefull for every tip and idea. I really have no idea what the Problem could be.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of optimization.

Try to do a [Profiling](https://reactnative.dev/docs/profiling#profiling-android-ui-performance-with-systrace) of your app on different phones to find the process that is more time consuming.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, I will try it. Perhaps I get some insights. I'm afraid this isn't the Problem thought. The app I use to test the component is really lightweight. Basically just two screens with each 6 components. Also, the Huawei drops frames, but the fairphone and xiaomi perform without problems. On the spec sheet, the Huawei is more performant than the other two. This makes me think it is likely not a performance Problem of the app.